How to understand the counterexample constructed in the PRP/PRF switching lemma towards the standard proof?
I'm reading a paper Code-Based Game-Playing Proofs and the Security of Triple Encryption , which indicates an error on the standard proof of the PRP/PRF switching lemma using the conditional probability in its chapter 2.
In the standard proof, it defines COLL and DIST events, which COLL means the adversary A asks distinct queries to the oracle and gets the same return, DIST is the complementary event. which makes $ Pr[A^{\pi}\Rightarrow 1]=Pr[A^{\rho }\Rightarrow 1|DIST]$.
Then the author constructed an counterexample of this equality, which event DIST is true for $(\rho(0),\rho(1))=(0,0),(0,1),(1,0)$, but I can't understand why the event $(0,0)$ are DIST. Is the adversary A asks distinct queries to the oracle and gets the same return, means a COLL?
Here is an excerpt from the relevant part of the paper below.




but I can't understand why the event $(\rho(0),\rho(1))=(0,0)$ is DIST

Because the adversary queries its oracle at 0, gets the answer $\rho(0)=0$, and halts. It does not query its oracle at input 1, therefore it never observes a repeated oracle output.

Thank you very much
